# Run jps -l command in java program and fetch output

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have to run jps -l command in my java program and fetch output. I have tried below mentioned code but it didn't work.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = rt.exec("jps -l");
```

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start jps -l");
```

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = rt.exec("powershell.exe jps -l");
```

Every time program output was :

```
Cannot run program "jps -l": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Is there any way to run "jps -l" and fetch output?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely jps is not on the system path. You can still run that executable, just provide the absolute path, e.g.

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-17.0.2\bin\jps.exe" -l
```

Mind the fact that 'Program Files' contains a whitespace which needs escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Environment variables for Java, refer [how to set java path](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) on how to set it.

> Proof:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("jps -l");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        // Read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // Read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Here is the standard output of the command:

17556 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jps.Jps
13320 com.example.demo.Test
22636 Eclipse
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

Done
```

> Environment Variable:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to get the output of this command normally in the command prompt?